# How do I create a SQL Linked Service for Azure Datafactory using the Azure CLI commands?

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

I am trying to get the Azure CLI commands working for creating linked services for Azure Datafactory. I was able to see what the request JSON looks like when it's being sent over the network via the Azure Portal / GUI and I get the following.

```
{
    "name": "sqltest_script",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "SqlServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Data Source=placeholderServer;Initial Catalog=placeholderDB;User ID=placeholderUser;Password=placeholderPass"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "placeholderRef",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/datafactory/linked-service?view=azure-cli-latest#az-datafactory-linked-service-create), I was able to see that we need to pass properties as a string when we are creating the Linked Service. So I took from the code block above and kept the "type", "typeProperties", and "connectVia" sections.

Following the format used in the documentation example, I converted the string to escape the quote characters.

```
"{\"type\": \"SqlServer\",\"typeProperties\": {\"connectionString\": \"Integrated Security=False;Data Source=placeholderServer;Initial Catalog=placeholderDB;User ID=placeholderUser;Password=placeholderPass\"},\"connectVia\": {\"referenceName\": \"placeholderRef\",\"type\": \"IntegrationRuntimeReference\"}}"
```

Then using that string with our --properties part of the command the final command that is entered into the CLI is,

```
az datafactory linked-service create --factory-name "placeholderFactory" --properties "{\"type\": \"SqlServer\",\"typeProperties\": {\"connectionString\": \"Integrated Security=False;Data Source=placeholderServer;Initial Catalog=placeholderDB;User ID=placeholderUser;Password=placeholderPass\"},\"connectVia\": {\"referenceName\": \"placeholderRef\",\"type\": \"IntegrationRuntimeReference\"}}" --name "scriptTest" --resource-group "placeholderResource"
```

When I try to run the command I get the following error,
[image: ParserError Image for Azure CLI command]

I believe I haven't created the --properties string correctly but am unsure of how to proceed. I was able to find some more [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linked-services/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#sqlserverlinkedservice) on the parameters that get passed in but I think my formatting for the string is incorrect.

## UPDATE:

I was able to get the creation working when I pass in a file containing the JSON. The file contents are,

```
{
    "type": "SqlServer",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Data Source=placeholderServer;Initial Catalog=placeholderDB;User ID=placeholderUser;Password=placeholderPass"
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "placeholderRef",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
}
```

and is named **createProperties.json**, then the new command that I am using is,

```
az datafactory linked-service create --factory-name "placeholderFactory" --properties createProperties.json --name "scriptTest" --resource-group "placeholderResource"
```

**I still need help with getting the properties string working in the command** but I have figured out how to use a file as input.

Comment: Have you tried executing in Azure bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
az datafactory linked-service create --factory-name "datafactory-name" --properties '{"type": "SqlServer","typeProperties": {"connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Data Source=<server name>;Initial Catalog=<database name>;User ID=<user id>;Password=<password>"}}' --name "script" --resource-group "resource-name"
```

This should work,

Result,

[image]

If you still face any issue, try in **Azure Bash**

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. If you can, what was wrong with the escape characters approach? (Purely from a learning perspective, no disrespect to your answer.)